# Solving a first order linear non-homogeneous ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

can someone help me figure out how this differential equation
\begin{equation}
y' = p(t)(1-y)
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
gives the following solution?
\begin{equation}
y = 1 + \exp\left[-\int_0^tp(s)ds\right]\left(y(0)-1\right)
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

I tried integrating factors, but I end stuck at this step:
\begin{equation}
y = e^{-\int_0^tp(s)ds}\left(\int e^{\int p(t)dt}p(t)dt + C\right)
\tag{3}
\end{equation}.

What's next or how else can I solve it so that we end up with the solution of Eq. 2?

Thanks so much in advanced!

Comment: Hi Jeffrey Alido, Welcome to MSE. it seems ok .but you can do other method to get result somehow clear

Answer (score 1):

separable diff. eq. $$y'=p(t)(1-y)\\\frac {dy}{dt}=p(t)(1-y)\\\frac {dy}{1-y}=p(t)dt\\\int_0^t \frac {dy}{1-y} = \int_0^t p(t)dt\\-\ln(1-y)|_0^t=\int_0^t p(t)dt\\\ln(\frac {1-y_0}{1-y})=\int_0^t p(t)dt\\\ln(\frac {1-y}{1-y_0})=-\int_0^t p(t)dt\\\frac {1-y}{1-y_0}=exp(-\int_0^t p(t)dt)$$ hope it helps